# Properties of prime mod $3$

Tags: prime-numbers

We know that if $p$ is a prime congruent to $3 \mod 4$, we cannot represent it as sum of two squares. Is there a positive property of such $p$? That is, do we have any statements that say "$p$ is a prime congruent to $3 \mod 4$ iff $\underline{\mbox{a positive statement}}$ is TRUE in an unique way". For instance, we have "$p$ is a prime congruent to $1 \mod 4$ iff $p=a^2+b^2$ and $|ab|>1$ in an unique way.

Comment: $p$ is congruent to $3 \bmod 4$ iff it remains prime in the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Yeah?

Comment: Also, please don't type in all caps like that. It's usually considered rude in an online setting (analogous to yelling).

Comment: yeah but you are transferring primality to some where else. Also the statement cannot be given proper meaning to rhyme with uniqueness.

Comment: corrected the all caps.

Comment: There is nothing. For, say $p \equiv 7 \pmod 8,$ we can say there is a minimal set of automorphism orbits solving $x^2 - 2 y^2 = p.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, we can say, a prime is $1,3 \pmod 8$ if and only if there is just one expression $p = x^2 + 2 y^2.$

You get a little flexibility by throwing in indefinite forms: a prime is $1,7 \pmod 8$ if and only if there are just two infinite sequences of expressions $p = x^2 - 2 y^2,$ under the action (and its inverse)
$$   
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
x \\
y
\end{array}
\right) \mapsto
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3 & 4 \\
2 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
x \\
y
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The two orbits for the prime $7$ have base points
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
3 \\
-1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
3 \\
1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Professor. Thank you for the answer. Could you please elucidate the meaning of "four squareclasses involving primes in the 2-adic numbers"? The matrix $(3 4; 2 3)$.. Is there a keyword for these unimodular matrices?

Answer (score 1):

I think I will leave the part about squareclasses alone.

Here is a diagram, of a design due to Conway, that organizes all column vectors
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
x \\
y
\end{array}
\right)
$$
of integers $x,y$ such that $x^2 - 2 y^2 = 1,-1,2,-2,7.$

[image]

Conway's book can be downloaded from [PDF](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/conwaysens.pdf). There is also a helpful discussion in [Stillwell, Elements of Number Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=LiAlZO2ntKAC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=stillwell%20elements%20of%20number%20theory%20map%20of%20primitive%20vectors&source=bl&ots=Pq-dR3tvf6&sig=IedQ5DaftH0US_Xw7DuJMBVRfNU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FAuKVPW-EZTToATWyIGAAQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=stillwell%20elements%20of%20number%20theory%20map%20of%20primitive%20vectors&f=false), particularly pages 87-99, that does a good job of showing how the value of the quadratic form and the $(x,y)$ points with $\gcd(x,y)=1$ match up, as I have illustrated for $x^2 - 2 y^2.$

Comment: Thank you but atleast at the stratospheric level how is this related to $2$-adic numbers? just curious?