# Longest sequence of consecutive quadratic residues mod $p$.

Tags: number-theory

### Background/Motivation

I am advising a number theory project for a group of students.  They are going to implement an algorithm to express any prime $p$ congruent to $1$ mod $4$  as a sum of two squares.

One thing they will need to do is to find a square root of $-1$ mod $p$.

My first thought is that since half of the numbers $1,2,3, ...$ are non quadratic residues mod $p$, they can just check $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ mod $p$ for $a = 2, 3, 4, ...$ until they get $-1$.  Computing these powers is relatively quick if they express $\frac{p-1}{2}$ in binary and use repeated squaring to find the values $a^{2^n}$ mod $p$.

This leads to the question of "worst case scenarios":  what if there is a long string of quadratic residues at the beginning of the sequence?

### Question

What is known about the longest string of consecutive quadratic residues mod $p$?  Can we say anything about the ratio of this number to $p$ as $p \to \infty$?

Comment: [Polya Vinogradov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#The_P.C3.B3lya.E2.80.93Vinogradov_inequality) is relatively elementary and gives $\sqrt{p} \log p$. The improvements (search for *least quadratic non-residue*) are much harder.

Comment: @reuns  Thanks!  I was missing this keyword.  If you post your comment as an answer, I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: see also Stan Wagon,   Editor's corner: The Euclidean algorithm strikes again, American Mathematical Monthly, 97 (1990) 125-129.  list at 
        http://stanwagon.com/wagon/misc/papers.html  The method I like is to use the square root of -1 mod p to construct a binary quadratic form $<p, 2b, c> $  or $px^2 + 2bxy + c y^2 $  of discriminant $-4$ Then Gauss reduce this to $<1,0,1>$ keeping track  of the change of  basis matrix;  at the end, invert this, the left column represents $p$  as $t^2 + u^2$

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I did another student project on this method.  We thought about the same thing from a topographic perspective.  Here is the code:  https://replit.com/@StevenGubkin/Fermats-Christmas-Theorem#main.py

Comment: Note this question about graphics: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078450/maps-of-primitive-vectors-and-conways-river-has-anyone-built-this-in-sage    I made a few programs to give the numbers for  parts of the topograph,  allowing me to draw the diagrams. Still a solid hour just to draw the river for a "reduced" indefinite  form with relatively small automorphism (generator) matrix.